# Controlling class label and color from classified image in GEE column chart?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, javascript, symbology, chart

I am trying to create a column chart from a land use/land cover (lulc) classified image (more specifically, the amount of area per lulc class). I was able to create the chart but **couldn't set the class labels and class colors (bar colors) right**.

By 'right' I mean, there are 22 possible classes and depending on which area of interest (which can vary) I am analyzing, not all 22 classes will be present in the scene. So, in the chart I need to keep the corresponding class name and class color (each class has already a pre-defined hard-coded color) with their matching class value in the image.

For example, in the picture below, the class with value 24 ('Infraestrutura Urbana' or Urban Infrastructure) appears in the map layer with correct color, and in the map legend with correct color and name. However, in the chart, the label of such class is incorrect. Where it reads: '24' should be '24 - Infraestrutura Urbana'. Also, the respective bar color in chart does not match the one from the map layer.

[image]

I don't necessarily need to stick to the chart type `ui.Chart.image.byClass`. I could use for example `ui.Chart.array.values` if it is the correct way to go (reduce data first, then chart with correct symbology). But how?

In other words, how to create a bar chart from a classified image and link class values, labels and bar colors independent if a given class is present in a given scene (area of interest) or not?

Here is the reproducible example to what I have got so far ([link to code in GEE editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd9c1fdc1130e9b71a6babd277aae311)).

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//INPUT DATA
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Image
var mapbiomas_lulc_asset = "projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection5/mapbiomas_collection50_integration_v1";
var mapbiomas_lulc = ee.Image(mapbiomas_lulc_asset);
mapbiomas_lulc = mapbiomas_lulc.select('classification_2019');
print('Mapbiomas - LULC, 2019', mapbiomas_lulc);

//AOI
//var aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-56.53, -16.87, -55.99, -16.46]); //example 1
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-49.14, -22.38, -48.97, -22.25]); //example 2
//var aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-68.78, -11.078, -67.128, -9]); // example 3
// example n;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//column CHART
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var labels = ["3 - Formação Florestal",
              "4 - Formação Savânica",
              "5 - Mangue",
              "9 - Floresta Plantada",
              "11 - Campo Alagado e Área Pantanosa",
              "12 - Formação Campestre",
              "13 - Outras Formações não Florestais",
              "15 - Pastagem",
              "20 - Cana",
              "21 - Mosaico de Agricultura e Pastagem",
              "23 - Praia e Duna",
              "24 - Infraestrutura Urbana",
              "25 - Outras Áreas não Vegetadas",
              "27 - Não Observado",
              "29 - Afloramento Rochoso",
              "30 - Mineração",
              "31 - Aquicultura",
              "32 - Apicum",
              "33 - Rio; Lago e Oceano",
              "36 - Lavoura Perene",
              "39 - Soja",
              "41 - Outras Lavouras Temporárias"
];

//chart_area
var chart_area = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
      image: ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).addBands(mapbiomas_lulc),
      classBand: 'classification_2019',
      region: aoi,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      scale: 100,
      classLabels: labels,
      xLabels:[]
    })
    .setChartType('ColumnChart')
    .setOptions({
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Area (hectares)',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
        gridlines: {color:'FFFFFF'},
        format:'short',
        baselineColor:'#000000',
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Land use/Land cover class',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
      },
    legend: {position:'right', title:'LULC classes'},
    series: {
      0: {color: "#006400"},
      1: {color: "#00ff00"},
      2: {color: "#687537"},
      3: {color: "#935132"},
      4: {color: "#45c2a5"},
      5: {color: "#b8af4f"},
      6: {color: "#f1c232"},
      7: {color: "#ffd966"},
      8: {color: "#c27ba0"},
      9: {color: "#fff3bf"},
      10:{color: "#dd7e6b"},
      11:{color: "#aa0000"},
      12:{color: "#ff0000"},
      13:{color: "#d5d5e5"},
      14:{color: "#b2ae7c"},
      15:{color: "#af2a2a"},
      16:{color: "#8a2be2"},
      17:{color: "#968c46"},
      18:{color: "#0000ff"},
      19:{color: "#f3b4f1"},
      20:{color: "#c59ff4"},
      21:{color: "#e787f8"}
    }
  });
print(chart_area);

/*
//Dictionary with class value and class label (for chart?)
var classLabels = {3:"Formação Florestal",
                  4:"Formação Savânica",
                  5:"Mangue",
                  9:"Floresta Plantada",
                  11:"Campo Alagado e Área Pantanosa",
                  12:"Formação Campestre",
                  13:"Outras Formações não Florestais",
                  15:"Pastagem",
                  20:"Cana",
                  21:"Mosaico de Agricultura e Pastagem",
                  23:"Praia e Duna",
                  24:"Infraestrutura Urbana",
                  25:"Outras Áreas não Vegetadas",
                  27:"Não Observado",
                  29:"Afloramento Rochoso",
                  30:"Mineração",
                  31:"Aquicultura",
                  32:"Apicum",
                  33:"Rio; Lago e Oceano",
                  36:"Lavoura Perene",
                  39:"Soja",
                  41:"Outras Lavouras Temporárias"
};
*/

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//map LAYER
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Map.centerObject(aoi);

var mapbiomas_lulc_class_color =
'<RasterSymbolizer>' +
  '<ChannelSelection>' + //used when image has more than one band (to specify which band in which channel).
    '<GrayChannel>' + 
        '<SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>' +
    '</GrayChannel>' +
  '</ChannelSelection>' +
  '<ColorMap type="values">' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#006400" quantity="3" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#00ff00" quantity="4" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#687537" quantity="5" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#935132" quantity="9" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#45c2a5" quantity="11" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#b8af4f" quantity="12" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#f1c232" quantity="13" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#ffd966" quantity="15" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#c27ba0" quantity="20" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#fff3bf" quantity="21" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#dd7e6b" quantity="23" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#aa0000" quantity="24" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#ff0000" quantity="25" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#d5d5e5" quantity="27" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#b2ae7c" quantity="29" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#af2a2a" quantity="30" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#8a2be2" quantity="31" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#968c46" quantity="32" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#0000ff" quantity="33" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#f3b4f1" quantity="36" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#c59ff4" quantity="39" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#e787f8" quantity="41" />' +
  '</ColorMap>' +
'</RasterSymbolizer>';

Map.addLayer(mapbiomas_lulc.clip(aoi), {}, 'LULC - inspection');
Map.addLayer(mapbiomas_lulc.clip(aoi).sldStyle(mapbiomas_lulc_class_color), {}, 'LULC - visualization');

//Legend
var legendPanel = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-right',
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }});
 
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'LULC class',
  style: {fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '15px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
    }});
 
legendPanel.add(legendTitle);
 
var makeRow = function(color, label) {
      var colorBox = ui.Label({
        style: {
          backgroundColor: color,
          padding: '8px',
          margin: '0 0 4px 0'
        }});
      var description = ui.Label({
        value: label,
        style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
      });
       return ui.Panel({
        widgets: [colorBox, description],
        layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
      })};
 
var palette =["#006400","#00ff00","#687537","#935132","#45c2a5","#b8af4f","#f1c232","#ffd966","#c27ba0","#fff3bf","#dd7e6b","#aa0000","#ff0000","#d5d5e5","#b2ae7c","#af2a2a","#8a2be2","#968c46","#0000ff","#f3b4f1","#c59ff4","#e787f8"];

for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
  legendPanel.add(makeRow(palette[i], labels[i]));
  }  
 
Map.add(legendPanel);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chart.image.byClass` is just calling a grouped reduceRegion.  Probably easiest to just build your own data table, so you can then configure the rest of the charting any way you want.

```
var palette = ee.List(["#006400","#00ff00","#687537","#935132","#45c2a5","#b8af4f","#f1c232","#ffd966","#c27ba0","#fff3bf","#dd7e6b","#aa0000","#ff0000","#d5d5e5","#b2ae7c","#af2a2a","#8a2be2","#968c46","#0000ff","#f3b4f1","#c59ff4","#e787f8"])
var values = ee.List([3, 4, 5, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 36, 39, 41])
var labels = ee.List(["3 - Formação Florestal",
              "4 - Formação Savânica",
              "5 - Mangue",
              "9 - Floresta Plantada",
              "11 - Campo Alagado e Área Pantanosa",
              "12 - Formação Campestre",
              "13 - Outras Formações não Florestais",
              "15 - Pastagem",
              "20 - Cana",
              "21 - Mosaico de Agricultura e Pastagem",
              "23 - Praia e Duna",
              "24 - Infraestrutura Urbana",
              "25 - Outras Áreas não Vegetadas",
              "27 - Não Observado",
              "29 - Afloramento Rochoso",
              "30 - Mineração",
              "31 - Aquicultura",
              "32 - Apicum",
              "33 - Rio; Lago e Oceano",
              "36 - Lavoura Perene",
              "39 - Soja",
              "41 - Outras Lavouras Temporárias"
])

// Compute the area of each class.
var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).addBands(mapbiomas_lulc)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1), 
    geometry: aoi, 
    scale: 100
  }).get('groups')

// A dictionary of default values to fill in 0's for missing classes.
var defaults = ee.Dictionary(labels.map(function(label) {
  var index = labels.indexOf(label)
  return [label, 0]
}).flatten())

// Convert the list of group dictionaries into one big dictionary.
areas = ee.Dictionary(ee.List(areas).map(function(dict) {
  dict = ee.Dictionary(dict)
  var value = dict.getNumber('sum')
  var klass = dict.getNumber('group')
  var index = values.indexOf(klass)
  var label = labels.get(index)
  return [label, value]
}).flatten())

// Combine with the defaults to fill in missing values, and add a color column.
var result = areas.combine(defaults, false).map(function(k, v) {
  var index = labels.indexOf(k)
  return [k, v, palette.get(index)]
}).values(labels)

// Append the data table header.
result = result.insert(0, ['Label', 'Area', { role: 'style' }])

//chart_area
var chart_area = ui.Chart(result.getInfo())
    .setChartType('ColumnChart')
    .setOptions({
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Area (hectares)',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
        gridlines: {color:'FFFFFF'},
        format:'short',
        baselineColor:'#000000',
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Land use/Land cover class',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
      },
    legend: {position:'right', title:'LULC classes'}
  })
print(chart_area)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/64dcb193e65ddfd87e07db507cb7467c